# Python easy_install wrong version conflict

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, easy-install

I try to build docker-compose from source with setuptools like this

```
python setup.py develop
```

But I get the follwoing error:

```
error: requests 2.11.1 is installed but requests!=2.18.0,>=2.14.2 is required by set(['docker'])
```

but running

```
pip show requests
```

gives the following result:

```
Name: requests
Version: 2.18.4
Summary: Python HTTP for Humans.
Home-page: http://python-requests.org
Author: Kenneth Reitz
Author-email: me@kennethreitz.org
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /home/florian/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: certifi, chardet, idna, urllib3
```

Is there anything cached by setuptools or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue in the git repo source code, that blocked me from building.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
sudo pip install --upgrade docker-compose
```